# RxJava: one request -> list of integers -> sequence of requests for each int -> result into list

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm a newbie in RxJava and I have some difficulties while constructing Observable.

My tasks are:

1. Query to server getExpPointsIdArrayByHouse
2. On server response. We get an object (RpcDeviceInfoResponse) that contain a list of integers
3. For each of int value a separate query to server is needed to be executed. Result of the each query is an object "ExpPoint"
4. Final result is a list of expPoints

What I've already done:

```
Observable
        .defer(new Func0() {
            @Override
            public Object call() {
                try {
                    return Observable.just(apiHttpClient.getExpPointsIdArrayByHouse(houseId));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return Observable.error(e);
                } catch (RightsException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return Observable.error(e);
                }
            }
        })
    .flatMap(new Func1<RpcDeviceInfoResponse, Observable<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Integer> call(RpcDeviceInfoResponse rpcResponse) {

            if (rpcResponse.getResult().size() == 0) {
                errorReport(false, context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_while_getting_exp_points), "");
                return null;
            }

            RpcDeviceInfoResponse.TaskListResult result = rpcResponse.getResult().get(0);
            return Observable.from(result.getResult());

        }
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.v("onCompleted", "onCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.v("onError", "onError");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer integer) {
            Log.v("onNext", "onNext");


        }
    });
```

I got stuck at the point 3. I have a list of integers and for each I need to execute a separate query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have an `Observable<Int>` so you can use `flatMap`

```
Observable.defer(
        //first query
    ).flatMap(
        // convert result to Observable<Int>
    )
    .flatMap(
        someInt -> doSomeQuery(someInt)
    )
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: In my case, as far as I am concerned, it is better to use map after flatMap (returned value is not Observable)Thank you!

Comment: if `doSomeQuery` doesn't return an `Observable` then yes, use `map` instead. However, since you're making (I assume) an HTTP request consider moving to [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) and modifying your API so your services return an `Observable`